# sha1 function in db2 AS400

Tags: db2, db2-400

In Mysql,

`Sha1` function returns 40 byte length output for any input length.

For Example,

```
select sha1('ABCD');
```

> output:fb2f85c88567f3c8ce9b799c7c54642d0c7b41f6

Similar to Mysql,

Please help me finding out what function is **equivalent of `sha1` in db2 iseries/AS400**?

Answer (score 1):

On DB2 for i, you can use `ENCRYPT_AES`, `ENCRYPT_RC2`, or `ENCRYPT_TDES`, but there is no `SHA1` function. You can find documentation here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscaencryptaes.htm

Answer (score 0):

While DB2 for i does not currently have a built-in SHA-1 function, you could perhaps write your own [user defined function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/sqlp/rbafyudf.htm), using the [Cryptographic Services APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/catcrypt.htm) and the [Calculate Hash API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/qc3calha.htm)